# How to check the dotnet cli version in VS2017?

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core

I created a `.NET Core web app` in visual studio (just updated VS2017 to `15.0.26119.0 D15REL`), but when I tried to **build it on the command line** with `dotnet restore; dotnet build`, it fails

my `dotnet --version` outputs `1.0.0-preview4-004233`. it looks like my `dotnet cli` is outdated since the build succeed after I installed [1.0.0-rc3-004517](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/rc3-download.md)

Does VS updates comes with its own [dotnet cli](https://github.com/dotnet/cli)? if so, how can I find **its version** in VS?
if not...how do I know which standard does VS follow when creating .NET core web apps? (so I can use the matching `dotnet cli` outside VS)

**[Updates]** Here's a workaround: compare msbuild engine **version** by running

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe
>Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.1.523.56541

dotnet "C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\sdk\1.0.0-preview4-004233\MSBuild.dll
>Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.1.458.808
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how one can check dot net version using VS 2017 command prompt.

[image: This is how one can check dot net version using VS 2017 command prompt]

Answer (score 1):

> how can I find its version in VS?

To determine what version of the `dotnet SDK` Visual Studio is using, take the following steps.

1. Open your project in Visual Studio.
2. Click Project > Properties > Build Events
3. In the Pre-build event command line, paste `dotnet --version`.
4. Save All <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>
5. View output <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>
6. Build <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>

The output will look something like this, in which case the SDK version is `1.0.0-preview4-004233`.

```
1>------ Build started: Project: MyProject, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>1.0.0-preview4-004233
1>MyProject-> C:\MyProject\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.0\MyProject.dll
========== Build: 1 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Just tested, this is equivalent of running `dotnet --version` on the command line...which will return my installed `1.0.0-preview4-004233`. I can have a very ancient version installed in my `C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\sdk`, whereas I need [1.0.0-rc3-004517](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/rc3-download.md) to build my VS2017 project

Comment: @watashiSHUN I also tried running a build with Diagnostic output, to see if the dotnet version is listed there. It was not. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/msbuild/2005/09/28/cranking-up-the-build-verbosity-in-the-ide/

Comment: yup, maybe VS2017 update does not have it's own version of `dotnet cli`. it just created the project that can be understood by a particular version of msbuild...so if you want to compile your VS2017 project in linux, you need to find the matching msbuild engine version? just a theory, not confirmed